# Java Regex to Parse a Path Into Multiple Optional Groups

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split this type string using a Java Regex:

```
/api/vX/client/domain/category/id
```

crudely into this:

```
(?:/api)?(?:/vX)?(/client/domain/...)?(?:/category)?(?:...)?
```

I would split it into the following groups:

- [0] /api
- [1] /vX (1-x)
- [2] /client/domain (/a/b/...) (up to category below)
- [3] /category1 | /category2
- [4] /everything else

Right now, I am trying to us a regex like this but it is just not working the way I am expecting it to.

```
(\/api)?(\/v\d+)?(\/\w+)(\/category1|category2\/?.*)?
```

I also need to take into account trailing/leading slashes with the expectation a leading slash will always start a segment but a trailing slash may or may not be there (unless there is a next segment).

**Some example of paths and outputs I am trying to achieve are:**

```
/client: 
[0], [1], [2]=/client, [3], [4]

/api/client: 
[0]=/api, [1], [2]=/client, [3], [4]

/api/v1/client/domain: 
[0]=/api, [1]=/v1, [2]=/client, [3], [4]

/api/v1/client/domain/category1: 
[0]=/api, [1]=/v1, [2]=/client/domain, [3]=/category1, [4]

api/v1/client/d1/d2/d3/category1: 
[0]=/api, [1]=/v1, [2]=/client/d1/d2/d3, [3]=/category1, [4]

/api/v2/client/domain/category2/id: 
[0]=/api, [1]=/v2, [2]=/client/domain, [3]=/category2, [4]=/id
```

Comment: [Have a look at Regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/ekebh6), idea maybe helpful. Click on Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following regex will match what you defined:

```
 ^(/api)?(/v\d+)?(/[^/]+(?:/[^/]+)*?)??(?:(/category[12])(/.*)?)?$
```

- `^` matches the start of line
- `(/api)?` group **1** (optional)
- `(/v\d+)?` group **2** (optional)
- `(/[^/]+(?:/[^/]+)*?)??` group **3** matches any number of groups, for client, domain, etc. (optional)

  - Both the outter and the inner group have a **[lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)**, to allow a match in categories.
  - `[^/]+` is a **[character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)** that matches anything except slashes.
- `(?:(/category[12])(/.*)?)?` is an optional **[non capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)** that matches:

  - `(/category[12])` category1 or 2 in group **4**
  - `(/.*)?` group **5**: anything else (optional)
- `$` the end of string (this is important to force lazy matches to capture all the text)

---

**Code**

```
String text = "/api/v2/client/domain/category2/id";
String pattern = "^(/api)?(/v\\d+)?(/[^/]+(?:/[^/]+)*?)??(?:(/category[12])(/.*)?)?$";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = regex.matcher(text);

while (m.find())
{
    System.out.println("api: " + m.group(1) + 
                       "\nversion: " + m.group(2) +
                       "\nclient: " + m.group(3) +
                       "\ncategory: " + m.group(4) +
                       "\nextra: " + m.group(5));
}
```

**Output**

```
api: /api
version: /v2
client: /client/domain
category: /category2
extra: /id
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/QQkSRh)</kbd>